# Fused operators on views much slower than nested loop in Julia

Tags: performance, julia

I am trying to make a function that computes a diffusion kernel as fast as possible by using `view` and fused operators. Is it possible to get the second function as fast as the first? Currently, `diff` takes 59.6 ms, whereas `diff_view` takes 384.3 ms.

```
using BenchmarkTools


function diff(
        at::Array{Float64, 3}, a::Array{Float64, 3},
        visc::Float64, dxidxi::Float64, dyidyi::Float64, dzidzi::Float64,
        itot::Int64, jtot::Int64, ktot::Int64)

    for k in 2:ktot-1
        for j in 2:jtot-1
            @simd for i in 2:itot-1
                @inbounds at[i, j, k] += visc * (
                    (a[i-1, j  , k  ] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i+1, j  , k  ]) * dxidxi +
                    (a[i  , j-1, k  ] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i  , j+1, k  ]) * dyidyi +
                    (a[i  , j  , k-1] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i  , j  , k+1]) * dzidzi )
            end
        end
    end
end


function diff_view(
        at::Array{Float64, 3}, a::Array{Float64, 3},
        visc::Float64, dxidxi::Float64, dyidyi::Float64, dzidzi::Float64,
        itot::Int64, jtot::Int64, ktot::Int64)

    at_c = view(at, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)

    a_c = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_w = view(a, 1:itot-2, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_e = view(a, 3:itot  , 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_s = view(a, 2:itot-1, 1:jtot-2, 2:ktot-1)
    a_n = view(a, 2:itot-1, 3:jtot  , 2:ktot-1)
    a_b = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 1:ktot-2)
    a_t = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 3:ktot  )

    at_c .+= visc .* ( (a_w .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_e) .* dxidxi .+
                       (a_s .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_n) .* dyidyi .+
                       (a_b .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_n) .* dzidzi )
end


itot = 384
jtot = 384
ktot = 384

a = rand(Float64, (itot, jtot, ktot))
at = zeros(Float64, (itot, jtot, ktot))

visc = 0.1
dxidxi = 0.1
dyidyi = 0.1
dzidzi = 0.1

@btime diff(
        at, a,
        visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi,
        itot, jtot, ktot)

@btime diff_view(
        at, a,
        visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi,
        itot, jtot, ktot)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the vectorized version is slower, but you can try interpolating the input arguments in the benchmark expressions using `$`. But the loop version is so much cleaner and easier to understand, the `view` version is almost impossible to understand. This is a typical example where you should use loops. Broadcasting should be used when it makes your code more readable, not otherwise.

Comment: BTW, it's not good style to pass the size of arrays as separate input arguments, it's also error-prone and verbose. Instead, query the sizes of the arrays using the `size` function.

Comment: @DNF. I agree that the loop version is the easiest. I am only learning Julia, and I have this benchmark written in many languages and expressions, hence I wanted to figure out what the second function is doing exactly and why it is so slow.

Comment: @DNF. This does not work if the number of ghost cells is runtime determined. In that case I have to provide the loop ranges to the function, unless you know a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what ghost cells are, do you mean if `itot` is less than `size(a)`, etc?

Comment: As for speed, it is possible that the loop simd-vectorizes, while the broadcast expressions do not. The compiler doesn't know that the various views are consecutive in memory, and cannot exploit cache locality, possibly. Use `@code_llvm` to check for simd vectorization.

Comment: One thing you could try is the `@turbo` macro from LoopVectorization.jl, which also works on broadcast expressions. Also check out multithreading.

Comment: @DNF, i meant that the first and last n cells are not used in the computation. I have here for instance 1 ghost cell on both sides, because my loop ranges from `2` tot `itot-1`. I hardcoded the value in this example, but the actual use case this number is dependent on the user.

Comment: Then, just pass in `Nghost`?

Comment: @turbo solves it! Would you like to prepare an answer so you get the credits you deserve? I will look into Nghost.

Comment: Maybe I can make an answer when I'm at my computer. Good to hear it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl)'s `@turbo` macro, which will make sure that the broadcast compiles to efficient SIMD instructions wherever possible.

```
using LoopVectorization
function diff_view_lv!(
        at::Array{Float64, 3}, a::Array{Float64, 3},
        visc::Float64, dxidxi::Float64, dyidyi::Float64, dzidzi::Float64,
        itot::Int64, jtot::Int64, ktot::Int64)

    at_c = view(at, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)

    a_c = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_w = view(a, 1:itot-2, 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_e = view(a, 3:itot  , 2:jtot-1, 2:ktot-1)
    a_s = view(a, 2:itot-1, 1:jtot-2, 2:ktot-1)
    a_n = view(a, 2:itot-1, 3:jtot  , 2:ktot-1)
    a_b = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 1:ktot-2)
    a_t = view(a, 2:itot-1, 2:jtot-1, 3:ktot  )

    @turbo at_c .+= visc .* ( (a_w .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_e) .* dxidxi .+
                       (a_s .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_n) .* dyidyi .+
                       (a_b .- 2. .* a_c .+ a_n) .* dzidzi )
    # Could also use @turbo @. to apply the broadcast to every operator, so you don't have to type `.` before each one.
end
```

As a stylistic aside, since all these functions mutate `at`, they should have names that end with `!` to denote that they mutate their argument.

And, as the comments noted, we want to be sure to interpolate any global variables into the benchmark with `$`. But other than that, using the same setup as in your question above (on what seems to be  a slightly slower CPU):

```
julia> @benchmark diff!(
               $at, $a,
               $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
               $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 50 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  100.575 ms … 101.855 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     100.783 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   100.798 ms ± 173.505 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

         ▆▁▁█▄
  ▄▄▄▄▄▆▇█████▇▆▄▆▁▁▁▄▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄ ▁
  101 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          102 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark diff_view!(
               $at, $a,
               $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
               $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 13 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  397.203 ms … 397.800 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     397.427 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   397.436 ms ± 173.079 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▁ ▁    ▁     ▁  ▁  ▁  ▁ ▁ █                ▁  ▁             ▁
  █▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁█▁▁█▁▁█▁█▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█ ▁
  397 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          398 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark diff_view_lv!(
               $at, $a,
               $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
               $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 61 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  82.226 ms …  83.015 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     82.364 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   82.395 ms ± 115.205 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

         ▁▄  ▁▁▁▁▄▄▄█▁  ▄  ▁█ ▁▁ ▁ ▁      ▁
  ▆▁▁▆▁▁▁██▆▁█████████▆▆█▆▆██▁██▁█▆█▁▁▁▁▁▁█▆▆▆▁▁▁▆▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▆ ▁
  82.2 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         82.7 ms <

 Memory estimate: 1008 bytes, allocs estimate: 41.
```

With this, the broadcasted version is now faster than the original looped version! However, as the comments have noted, the simple looping approach is arguably cleaner and more readable, and (as you might guess from the name) you can apply `LoopVectorization` to the looped version just as well:

```
using LoopVectorization
function diff_lv!(
        at::Array{Float64, 3}, a::Array{Float64, 3},
        visc::Float64, dxidxi::Float64, dyidyi::Float64, dzidzi::Float64,
        itot::Int64, jtot::Int64, ktot::Int64)

    @turbo for k in 2:ktot-1
        for j in 2:jtot-1
            for i in 2:itot-1
                at[i, j, k] += visc * (
                    (a[i-1, j  , k  ] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i+1, j  , k  ]) * dxidxi +
                    (a[i  , j-1, k  ] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i  , j+1, k  ]) * dyidyi +
                    (a[i  , j  , k-1] - 2. * a[i, j, k] + a[i  , j  , k+1]) * dzidzi )
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```
julia> @benchmark diff_lv!(
               $at, $a,
               $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
               $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 56 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  89.489 ms …  90.166 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     89.657 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   89.660 ms ± 103.127 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

         ▁    ▁ ▁       █▃   ▆ ▁
  ▄▁▁▄▁▁▄█▄▁▁▄█▄█▄▁▄▇▇▇▇██▄▄▇█▇█▁▁▁▄▄▁▁▁▁▄▁▄▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄ ▁
  89.5 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         89.9 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

Finally, if you want to multithread, you can just add another `t` in the name of the macro (`@tturbo` instead of `@turbo`)

```
julia> @benchmark diff_lvt!(
               $at, $a,
               $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
               $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 106 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  47.225 ms … 47.560 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     47.434 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   47.432 ms ± 67.185 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

                                 ▁ ▁▁ ▄▂       █  ▂
  ▃▁▁▃▁▁▅▁▁▅▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▃▃▃▃▃▁▅▅▃▅▅▃█▃██▃██▃▃▆▃▃▅▆█▆▅██▆▆▅▅▃▃▁▃▆ ▃
  47.2 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        47.5 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

which should provide some additional speedup as long as you have started Julia with multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, beautiful answer. It is not clear to me what the dollar sign does. I do not see performance difference, and I do not understand what "interpolating into" refers to.

Comment: Ah, so in this case the operation being benchmarked is probably long enough that it doesn't really make much of a difference one way or the other, but it's described a bit [here](https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/dev/manual/#Interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions)  in the BenchmarkTools docs.

Comment: Basically, global variables are slow, but if you're benchmarking at the REPL that's by default global scope. The "interpolation" provides a way to insulate the code being benchmarked from that global scope.

Comment: I still do not get it, if I pass them into the function, they are in the local scope of my `diff` functions, right?

Comment: AFAIU (since this is at the limit of my understanding): once they're _in_ the function, yes. However, when you first pass them to the function, if they are globals, Julia's compiler can't be sure until runtime what their types actually are, so to be safe it will then have to either recompile your function for whatever type they actually are, _every time_, or else compile your function with some sort of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: In general, this gets into the Julia concept of _type stability_, which can take a while to wrap your mind around because it really only exists in "dispatch-oriented" languages, of which Julia is likely the first one most users have ever experienced.

Comment: See also e.g. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/function-calls-in-global-scope-benchmarking-etc/27513